# Harmonic and Digamma function

Tags: sequences-and-series, digamma-function

I am a master's student, I have a little experience in harmonic numbers. I know the $H_{n} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k}$ .

I am wondering what the $H_{(\frac{1}{k}-1)}$ is. I am trying to rewrite it as a series like $H_{n}$. I got $H_{(\frac{1}{k}-1)} = \digamma(1/k)+ \psi$, But I think there is something wrong because when I try numbers in Python I get different results. How can I write it as a series and Digamma function?

Any help is welcome.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: How did you get that result? Please explain your calculations in an [edit], and use MathJax.

Comment: Please use more descriptive titles.

Comment: Why the [tag:probability-theory] tag?

Comment: [$H_z=\gamma+\psi(1+z)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Harmonic_numbers_for_real_and_complex_values).